# Udev Symbolic Link is not trigger on replug

Tags: ubuntu, udev

I am having a very weird behavior with one of my usb device If the device is plugged in during boot then the symbolic link is correctly followed the udev rule.

If I unplug and replug the device, the symbolic link is now pointed to a bus address rather than `/dev/tty*`.

I would have to do `sudo udevadm` trigger for it to update to correct value.

This is my udev rule

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7523", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", MODE:="0666", OWNER:="root", GROUP:="plugdev", SYMLINK+="canusb"
```

Correct Symbolic Link

```
ls /dev/canusb -l lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jul 5 09:18 /dev/canusb -> ttyUSB0
```

Wrong Symbolic Link when replug device

```
ls /dev/canusb -l lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 5 09:16 /dev/canusb -> bus/usb/001/005
```